# MSB4019 from VS2012 solution when building on Jenkins

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2012, msbuild, jenkins, windows-7-x64

I'm setting up our build server. I've installed Jenkins on a Windows 7 machine and am running into problems when building the 64 bit version of our solution.

We're using Visual Studio 2012 Express for Windows Desktop. Jenkins uses the MSBuild plugin and is targeting the 64 bit MSbuild exe at

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe
```

However, when it runs msbuild an evironment variable is not being parsed properly. VCTargetsPath.

If I leave everything as-is then the output of MSBuild is this

> error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" was not found. Confirm that the path in the  declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.

I played around a bit with the VCTargetsPath variables in the registry, Windwos Environment Variables and as Jenkins Eviornment Variables too. I noticed this behavior.

If I set VCTargetsPath to be "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V110" then the output of msbuild is the same as above. However, if I set it to "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0" then the output changes to this.

> error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\progra~2\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" was not found. Confirm that the path in the  declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.

The tile Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props is found in "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V110" I checked the limits on environment variable length and it's supposed to be 2048 characters. Am I missing something obvious here? I've found some info that basically says I am going to have to reinstall everything in a specific order, which is quite annoying (but also very Microsofty).

Answer (score 6):

I fixed this by adding
`/p:VCTargetsPath="C:\Program Files\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V120"`
**or** the more elegant
`/p:VisualStudioVersion=12.0`

into 
`Build > Build a Visual Studio project or solution using MSBuild > Command Line Arguments`

Answer (score 0):

Your first round of fix-it attempts for a build server.

Install the appropriate SDK on the build machine.

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8279

If that doesn't work, report back.

EDIT:

`/p:VisualStudioVersion=11.0`

Add that to your command line...as a parameter for msbuild.exe

EDIT:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe
```

I have a 64 bit version of msbuild.exe there.
Which isn't what you show.
I'm throwing a guess out, nothing concrete, FYI.

Comment: Just installed it and now I'm getting errors "MSB8008: Specified platform toolset (v110) is not installed or invalid". Going to poke around with this.

Comment: Is your target framework...4.0 or 4.5 on the csproj(?) that you're trying to build.

Comment: this is a native C++ application. It's platform toolset is v110.

Comment: Then the /p parameter hint is all I got.

Comment: thanks but that didn't work either. i have a feeling that installing the sdk on top of vs2012 broke something. Gonna have a deep breath then dive back into this.

Answer (score 0):

Try passing : /p:PlatformTarget=x86 as one of the arguments to MSBuild.